# How to fix function problems in npm package?

Tags: javascript, npm, package.json

I built a simple npm package for work with URL. it's working perfectly when you use it locally but when I published the package, I got many different errors that I am going to write it down and it would be perfect if you can help to solve those problems.
package is available [here][1].

code:

```js
var getUrl = function(){
    let originalUrl = window.location.href;
    return originalUrl;
}

var slashDivider = function(){
    let sd = getUrl().split('/');
    return sd;
}

let getProtocol = () => {
    let gp = location.protocol;
    return gp;
}

let domainName = () => {
    let dn = location.hostname;
    return dn;
}

let domainWithProtocol = () => {
    let dwp = location.origin;
    return dwp;
}

let sitePort = () => {
    let sp = location.port;
    return sp;
}

let searchQuery = () => {
    let sq = location.search;
    return sq;
}

let pathName = () => {
    let pn = location.pathname;
    return pn;
}

let hashAddress = () => {
    let hd = location.hash;
    return hd;
}

let StringIndexFinder = (nameOfString) => {
    let stringToArray = nameOfString.split('');
    let stringArrayLength = stringToArray.length;
    let startingIndex = getUrl().indexOf(nameOfString);
    let endIndex = parseInt(stringArrayLength) + parseInt(startingIndex) - 1;
    return "from index " + startingIndex + ", end index " + endIndex ;
} 


let isEncrypted = () => {
    if(getUrl().includes("https")){
        return true;
    } else {
        return false;
    }
}

module.exports = [getUrl, slashDivider, getProtocol, domainName, domainWithProtocol,sitePort,searchQuery, pathName,hashAddress, StringIndexFinder, isEncrypted];
```

1_ I installed the package by `npm i ulio --save` and then call package function like this:

```js
const getUrl = require('ulio');

console.log(getUrl())
```

and I got this error:

```
Uncaught TypeError: getUrl is not a function
```

2_ I made a small change in the package, I deleted all the functions and only kept the first function which is the getUrl, and it worked well!!!(why?)

```js
const getUrl = require('ulio');

console.log(getUrl()) //output: http://localhost:1234/
```

then I add the second function which is the slashDivider and the code become like below:

```js
var getUrl = function(){
    let originalUrl = window.location.href;
    return originalUrl;
}

var slashDivider = function(){
    let sd = getUrl().split('/');
    return sd;
} 

module.exports = getUrl;
module.exports = slashDivider;
```

by the following code, I got a result of a second function as a result of the first function too.

```
const getUrl = require('ulio');
const slashDivider = require('ulio');

console.log(getUrl())
console.log(slashDivider())
```

3_ now I published full package(include all functions) and get this error while trying `console.log(isEncrypted())`
error:

```
Uncaught TypeError: isEncrypted is not a function
```

and it's the same for all functions.
How can I solve those problems and how can I make this package better?
[1]: https://www.npmjs.com/package/ulio

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is happening because `module.exports` is being exported as an array. The first item is `getUrl`. Use this instead:

```js
const getUrl = require('ulio')[0];
console.log(getUrl())
```

Of course, this will not work unless using Browserify or Webpack, because `window` will not be defined.

A better way to do this is to use `module.exports` as an object, like this:

```js
module.exports = {
  getUrl: getUrl
  ...
}
```

Then, you can just use this:

```js
const { getUrl, someOtherFunction } = require('ulio');
console.log(getUrl())
console.log(someOtherFunction())
```

The following code:

```js
const getUrl = require('ulio');
console.log(getUrl())
```

Does not work, because, `require('ulio')` returns an array, and arrays cannot be called as functions.